# How to match the name of a worksheet to a certain input? (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

In my workbook, worksheets end with a date that represents them (MM/YY) i.e. "Final Stock 0916".
To make a procedure that only applied to a certain sheet I defined x and y as input boxes where you'd type year and month, respectively, and then somewhere among this:

```
If (x = "2016" And y = "September") Or (x = "2016" And y = "september") Then
Sheets("Final Stock 0916").Activate 'and type the code I want for this sheet
```

Is there a way to automatically match the input of x and y with the end of the name of the worksheet (which represents the date) in order to be able to add more worksheets without changing the code?

Comment: Note: If you use multiple `and` and `or` in one `If` statement I highly recommend to use parentheses! Otherwise you easily end up in a mess: `If (x = "2016" And y = "September") Or (x = "2016" And y = "september") Then`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a function to return the sheet name from the values of x and y:

```
Function s_name(x, y)
    m = Split("january,february,march,april,may,june,july,august,september,october,november,december", ",")
    For i = 0 To 11
        If LCase(y) = m(i) Then m_i = Format(i + 1, "00")
    Next i
    s_name = "Final Stock " & m_i & Mid(x, 3, 2)
End Function
```

Then, for example:

- s_name("2016", "september") will return the name "Final Stock 0916"
- s_name("2017", "March") will return the name "Final Stock 0317"

Then you can select the sheets calling the function:

```
Sheets(s_name("2016", "september")).Activate
    'type the code for sheet Final Stock 0916

Sheets(s_name("2017", "March")).Activate
    'type the code for sheet Final Stock 0317
```